# ActiveMQ messages not dequeued untill accessing the Web admin list

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Our architecture is based on a ActiveMQ 5.10.0 backbone that consists of about 70 queues. Different applications send messages to queues and different applications consumes messages from queues.
In details, only 5 queues have more than one consumer while the remaining have one single consumer per queue.

Everything works fine except for the queues with multiple consumers. For these queues, messages are correctly queued but they are not dequeued untill we access to the ActiveMQ Web portal and click on the queue name thus enlisting the full message list. When we do this, suddendly pending messages are dequeued.

Some additional notes:

- the queue only contains TEXT messages
- we have 10 consumers registered to that queue. Every consumer defines a proper selector in order to consume only some of the published messages.
- every message set a timeout since there are messages that doesn't match any selector rule and we don't want to keep messages in the queue indefinitely.
- every consumer defines a connection pool via BiTronix pool. According to what suggested in another thread, for every consumer we set the prefetch to 0

Can someone give us any advice? Why accessing the ActiveMQ Web message list unlock the unqueued messages?